# jquery: Choosing a document.ready method

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I'm new to jquery. I've just read that these 2 are equivalent:

`$(document).ready(function() {});`

`$(function() {});`

Which one is better practice, or more accepted? The first one strikes me as clearer in that it states the "document.ready" part - but then again, I'm new to jquery. It could be that to anyone with any experience in jquery, the second option just as clearly implies "document.ready". Which of these options should I choose?

Comment: The shorter one duh `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feel free to use either one of them. Just as you think, the latter version is a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.

The first option was available since the beginning of jQuery releases as oppose to the second option.

Personally I prefer the second version for it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler);

$().ready(handler); //(this is not recommended)

$(handler);
```

Comment: I understand that. I'm just asking if there's any reason you would choose one over the other, considering that they're identical

Comment: That would depend a lot on what you're doing within `handler()`. Sometimes, there are clear disadvantages of using `ready()` vs not using it.