# Differences between document.ready and $function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, document-ready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)
>   [jquery: Choosing a document.ready method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307509/jquery-choosing-a-document-ready-method)

What is the difference between doing this

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event){
        alert("Thanks for visiting!");
    });
});
```

and this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        alert("Thanks for visiting!");
    });
});
```

Comment: The former is less wordy and, when you get used to the idiom, more readable. Otherwise they have the same effect.

Answer (score 48):

They are the same. Check out the jQuery [`.ready()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Here's a quote from the docs:

> **All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:**
>
> $(document).ready(handler)
>
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>
> $(handler)

Comment: lol. Never ceases to amaze me. Down-voted for a correct answer and a quote from the docs :)

Answer (score 12):

There is no difference in functionality between your examples - they both bind to DOM ready.

For reference, there are two points at which you can bind your jQuery code.

The first will execute when the DOM is ready (both are equivalent):

```
// full example
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code...
});

// shortened 
$(function() {
  // code...
});

// ES6 example with $ aliased, note this is not supported in IE
jQuery($ => {
  // code...
});
```

The second will execute when the page has finished loading all images, stylesheets etc.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  // code...
});
```

The second is useful when you need to get the `width()` or `height()` of an image. These properties are only available once the image has completely downloaded to the client system.

Also note that `$(window).load(fn);` is now deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Of course, in addition to binding, it's important to remember that initialization code sometimes needn't be bound to any event. Some can run as soon as it's read, per this [article](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/) by [Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/about-dave-ward/).

Answer (score 7):

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler) 
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended) 
$(handler)
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: IF they are equivalent, why isn't one recommended?

Comment: for clarity as of this date the doc says the `$(handler)` is recommended i.e. often seen as `$(function(){});` with the code in that function body