# jQuery difference in dom ready call

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document-ready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between document.ready and $function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396415/differences-between-document-ready-and-function)

I think it is a stupid question, but,
Can someone show me the differences between these two call types?

```
$(function(){
//do somenthing
});

and

$(document).ready(function(){
//do somenthing
});
```

Comment: Do a search and you'll find hundres of duplicate questions, and the answer is always the same, they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the exact same thing. The top one is just a shortcut

From jquery doc:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> $(document).ready(handler)
>   $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended) 
>   $(handler)

[.ready() jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler)

$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)

$(handler)
```

See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396415/differences-between-document-ready-and-function)