# JQuery problems in drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, document-ready

I'm having problems with `$(document).ready` function. The problem is that it is not executed and there are no errors. I have tried to change `$` to `jQuery`, but the result is the same. I'm sure that jQuery is loaded because other JQ functions work.

Here is my code:

```
(function($){
    alert( $(window).width() );
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(1);
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

The first alert is working fine but the second is not.

Comment: you dont need the inner document.ready

Comment: the code runs anyway.. http://jsfiddle.net/eahrG/

Comment: Where did you added you JS code? Is it included within the page?

Comment: Yes it's included in the top lines of the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Differences between document.ready and $function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9396415/829533)

They both are same

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

although the code you have provided should work but what you need to do is either use

```
(function($){
    alert( $(window).width() );
    alert(1); 
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert( $(window).width() );
    alert(1);
});
```

**Update**

Also take a look at `$.ready` documentation http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

What show Firebug console?
Try to debug with function:

```
console.log.("It's working!");
```

Most likely jQuery it wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: A friend suggested that I include my js with drupal_add_js();. It seams that is working.

Thanks for your help.